# umask not working as expected in other than home directory

Tags: permissions, apache-httpd, umask

I try to set up a deployer user for CI with Teamcity. I followed the instructions from this question on ServerFault: [What's the best way of handling permissions for apache2's user www-data in /var/www?](https://serverfault.com/questions/6895/whats-the-best-way-of-handling-permissions-for-apache2s-user-www-data-in-var)

The problem is that the Teamcity application is creating directories with `755` permissions and the apache(2.4) can't write in some of them. If I change the permissions to `775` manually, apache can write them.

Here's what I did to set uo the permissions:

1. I created a user `teamcity`.
2. Added `www-data` group to the user as secondary group
3. Changed the ownership of `/var/www` to `root:www-data`
4. Changed permissions for directories with:

   `find /var/www -type d -exec chmod 2775 {} +`

   and for files with:

   `find /var/www -type f -exec chmod 0664 {} +`
5. Added `umask 0002` to `/etc/profile`

Tested:

```
su teamcity
umask 
>0002
touch testfile
ls -l
>-rw-rw-r-- 1 teamcity teamcity        0 May 25 10:38 testfile
cd /var/www
touch testfile
ls -l
>-rw-rw-r--  1 teamcity www-data      0 Mai 25 10:42 testfile
```

For directories its the same. They are `rw` for user and group.

After a deployment the permissions of directories and files are `755` and not `775` as expected.

The Teamcity application is started as a service:

`start-stop-daemon --start  -c teamcity --exec /opt/TeamCity/bin/runAll.sh start`

It seems that I missed some detail, but can't find it.

System:

- Debian jessie
- Apache 2.4
- Teamcity 9

**Solution:**

I changed the startup script for the Teamcity service by adding `umask 002` before the startup command.

Comment: You mean to say that apache cannot *write* in those directories.

Comment: @ThomasDickey Yes, because after the deployment the permissions are set to 755 instead of 775.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the description, it seems that TeamCity is ignoring the umask.  Perhaps it sets the umask in its service script (which was not mentioned in the question).  If so, you could modify the script.  If not, since it's apparently a closed-source application *and* in Java, your ability to thwart that is limited.  You *could* make a cron job (running once per minute) which fixes the directory permissions.

Further reading:

- [How can I set the umask from within java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175303/how-can-i-set-the-umask-from-within-java)
- [teamcity-vagrant](https://github.com/rodm/teamcity-vagrant/blob/master/files/agent/bin/teamcity-agent) (possibly relevant script)
- [Install a Teamcity v9.x CentOS Build Agent](https://plone.lucidsolutions.co.nz/software-development/continuous-integration/teamcity/install-a-teamcity-v8.x-centos-build-agent) , example showing where to start looking for the service script in `systemd`.

Comment: Your links pointed me in the right direction. I changed the startup script for the Teamcity service by adding `umask 002` before the startup command.